# Pushing Foursquare's Swarm Check-In Data into a Google Maps Service

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web-mapping, foursquare-data

I've been using FourSquare's Swarm app to track my travels. I'd like to be able to plot the check-in locations on a Google Maps service (or any other web-based service outside of the Swarm App). I've had limited success so far (markers for only a handful of recent check-ins appear) using the Google Maps Javascript API and Foursquare's API.

There are several thousand check-ins over the last 6 years or so.

Is this possible, or does it exceed API usage limits?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the Foursquare API has a default limit, which displays the last 25 check-ins. In order to display more than 25 on the map, the Foursquare API request needs to include a limit parameter (which has a limit of 250).

You can update the url variable in the code to include &limit=250 at the end.

If you need to display more than 250 check-ins, you will need to make multiple API requests and combine the results.